# Using Cloud9 IDE and Mailgun getting this error Net::SMTPSyntaxError in Devise::RegistrationsController#create

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, cloud9-ide, mailgun

Trying to set up Mailgun for RoR4.2 app development environment but still getting the above error. As I understood from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27611099/devise-rb-netsmtpsyntaxerror-when-calling-send-reset-password-instructions) there is problem with config development file.

This is my config/environments/development.rb:

```
 config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
 config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true

 host = 'my_app.c9.io'
 config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: host }

 config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
 config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
 address: 'smtp.mailgun.org',
 port: '2525',
 domain:     ENV["MAILGUN_DOMAIN"],
 user_name:  ENV["MAILGUN_USERNAME"],
 password:   ENV["MAILGUN_PASSWORD"],
 authentication: :plain,
 enable_starttls_auto: true,
 }
```

As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29836510/cloud9-and-actionmailer-mailgun) I also checked environment variables in console, they are properly set. I'm using port 2525 as suggested [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/sending-mail/using-mailgun) and [here](https://docs.c9.io/v1.0/discuss/558190ce04ae5b0d002629d9). Any ideas what can be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I finally get the answer, for whatever reason Cloud9 don't accept environment variables here so I had to hardcode them and had to use "hashrocket" format:

```
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true

host = 'my_app.c9.io'
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: host }

config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
:address        => 'smtp.mailgun.org',
:port           => '2525',
:authentication => :plain,
:user_name      => 'postmaster@xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.mailgun.org',
:password       => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
:domain         => 'sandboxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.mailgun.org',
:enable_starttls_auto => true  
}
```

If anybody knows how to use environment variables in Cloud9 config development file please comment here.

Answer (score 0):

Try using port 587 or port 465.

> Cloud9 is currently hosted on Google's infrastructure, and therefore their rules apply to Cloud9 workspaces too. One of their restrictions is regarding SMTP. Basically what this means is:
>
> - Port 25 is blocked
> - Ports 587, 465, and 2525 can be used
> - Can only use Google Compute Engine partner services, like SendGrid and Google Apps
>
> For details on the matter, please check out [this article](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/sending-mail/).

Comment: I tried every single one but unfortunately neither of them worked. I finally found temporary solution, posted above.