# Sendgrid with Cloud9 via WebApi Python Option

Tags: python, sendgrid, cloud9-ide, sendgrid-api-v3

I am having problems using sendgrid from my Cloud9 Python environment. This is my code as suggested by SendGrid setup option.

NOTE: I generated an actual API, obviously "YOUR_API_KEY" was replaced with appropriate key.

echo "export SENDGRID_API_KEY='YOUR_API_KEY'" > sendgrid.env

echo "sendgrid.env" >> .gitignore

source ./sendgrid.env**

pip install sendgrid

```
# using SendGrid's Python Library
# https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-python
import sendgrid
import os
from sendgrid.helpers.mail import *

sg = sendgrid.SendGridAPIClient(apikey=os.environ.get('SENDGRID_API_KEY'))

    from_email = Email("test@example.com")
    to_email = Email("myemail@example.com")
    subject = "Sending with SendGrid is Fun"
    content = Content("text/plain", "and easy to do anywhere, even with Python")
    mail = Mail(from_email, subject, to_email, content)
    response = sg.client.mail.send.post(request_body=mail.get())


print(response.status_code)
print(response.body)
print(response.headers)
```

Getting this error Log

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "schedule.py", line 92, in
> <module>
>     response = sg.client.mail.send.post(request_body=mail.get())   File
> "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python_http_client/client.py",
> line 204, in http_request
>     return Response(self._make_request(opener, request))   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python_http_client/client.py",
> line 138, in _make_request
>     return opener.open(request)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 410, in open
>     response = meth(req, response)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 523, in http_response
>     'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 448, in error
>     return self._call_chain(*args)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 382, in _call_chain
>     result = func(*args)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 531, in http_error_default
>     raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp) urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 401: Unauthorized
```

So is this related to missing libraries? some Cloud9 restriction? It shouldn't since I am not even messing with the SMTP option.,

Answer (score 0):

So I found out that Cloud9 doesn't let you set environment variables so I had to hardcode my API KEY in the code above.

All credit goes to the author of [Using Cloud9 IDE and Mailgun getting this error Net::SMTPSyntaxError in Devise::RegistrationsController#create](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33565611/using-cloud9-ide-and-mailgun-getting-this-error-netsmtpsyntaxerror-in-devise) who found out about this when dealing with a similar problem.

Thanks!